# Do we need to validate JSON Web Token at client/consumer?

Tags: jwt

I am studying a bit about JSON Web Token. I understood that header+claims get signed by a secret key and the encoded result gets concatenated to "header.claims.signature" and finally sent back to client.

I have some basic doubts:

- Do we need to validate the token at client/consumer (once it receives from server, for sake of authenticity)? Is it a standard at all or not necessary?  Any example for reference on this?
- If the client needs to validate the token, I guess it has to know the secret key to decrypt/decode.  Is there any other way to ask client validate on its own without sharing server's secret key?
- If client knows the secret key, I guess it can create its own token too.  If such is the case, do the server need to accept such tokens (or is application/business dependent?)

Comment: To my understanding the client is not the consumer of the token, the client is the bearer. No, the client does not need to validate the token.  The consumer is whatever application needs to read the contents of the token which in some cases is the same as the issuer but not in all cases.

Comment: late answer below. Just found this question, because another question from you was linked in question today.

Answer (score 2):

> Do we need to validate the token at client/consumer

On client side you usually don't validate the token. Treat it just as an opaque token. Keep it safe and use it when making requests to the server.

> If the client needs to validate the token, I guess it has to know the secret key to decrypt/decode.
> As mentioned above, the client doesn't need to validate the token.

In any cases in which the authentication server (the instance that authenticates the user and issues the token) and the resource server (the instance that owns a proteceted resource and requires a token for authorization) are not the same, signing and validation of the token is usually done with asymmetric algorithms like `RS256` in which the private key is used to sign the token and only known by the authentication server, and the public key is used to verify the signature.

> If client knows the secret key, I guess it can create its own token too. If such is the case, do the server need to accept such tokens (or is application/business dependent?)

That's why a client should not know the secret key.
When symmetric key algorithms (e.g. HS256), in which the same key is used to sign and verify a signature are used, you can't allow the client to know the key, as it could be abused to create a fake token. Then JWT would be pointless. For asymmetric keys, there's no risk if the client knows the public key.